# PDFJET Does Not Work For En Empty Constructor

Tags: java, pdf

i want to use pdfjet for a Google app engine project.

i downloaded the Java jar from the pPdfjet home page.

i followed an example given in a stack-overflow example and the examples given in the home page.
all the examples uses an empty constructor: `PDF pdf=new PDF();`. However when i try to use it, 
it says that the constructor PDF() is undefined, further more all the method shown do not work:

`pdf.wrap()`: is undefined

`pdf.save("Example_03.pdf")`: is undefined

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the examples on their web page are out of date. Look at the examples in the zip download instead. This simple example works for me:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.pdf");
PDF pdf = new PDF(out);
Page page = new Page(pdf, Letter.PORTRAIT);
pdf.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: this is fine though FileOutputStream is not supported by appengine is the error i get if i used this example

Comment: Just write to an `OutputStream` that is supported. Presumably you'd be writing the output to a web request since you're using Google App Engine and it doesn't support writing files. So you'd want to get your `OutputStream` from `response.getOutputStream()`.

Comment: thanks this worked. Though i m not sure now where to specify the pdf name and if i have to email it someone after creation then how do i get the handle of the created pdf? plz guide

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is easy. Actually instead of taking from req.getOutputStream() directly create and instance of BytArrayOutputStream and use that.

For sending it just use out.toArray() as add it to the attacement part.